# How to allow a Spring Boot application to run different contexts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im a java developer, and im new to Spring Boot. In the past, Ive been used to package my application with different "commands" for NON spring boot projects that each serve different purposes, so when i dockerize it, i can decide what i want to run.

[Usual package declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcA1X.png)

This way, i can choose what i want my application to run via an environment variable. Is there a way to achieve this with Spring Boot? I dont want a web server to always run when i only want an instance of my application to update records on the Database every X minutes as an example, as opposed to running my API server.

My questions are:

> What is the common way professional developers tackle this problem?
>
> Should i just make a spring boot module and package all the dependencies my commands will have within it, then create a separate spring boot project for each command i intend to run?

I hope i was able to provide enough info, thank you kindly for reading!

I've searched online, and found out about the @Profile annotation, but i am not sure if this is what im looking for.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider a multi-module maven project setup where the spring boot application is the "web app" portion of your system and other modules provide other functionality.

https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module